# How select dates from the last 7 days with 5mins interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, intervals

I have table with dates and values like this:

```
+----------------------+-------+
|         time         | value |
+----------------------+-------+
| 2020-02-28 08:30:20  |    30 |
| 2020-02-28 08:30:25  |    15 |
| 2020-02-28 08:30:30  |    30 |
| 2020-02-28 08:30:35  |    10 |
+----------------------+-------+
```

I need dates from the last 7 days, every 5mins without seconds.

```
+-------------------+-------+
|       time        | value |
+-------------------+-------+
| 2020-02-28 08:30  | 30    |
| 2020-02-28 08:35  | 5     |
| 2020-02-28 08:40  | 30    |
| 2020-02-28 08:45  | 4     |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to create such a query?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: *I need dates even value is null or date doesn't exist.* Server cannot return the data which not exists in it. You must generate needed datetimes list and join your source data to it. And you must formulate some criteria which will define what value of a lot of values matched to one final datetime (like 4 records in your example data which all matches to one final record) must be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT($column, '%H:%i'),`value` FROM $table WHERE MOD(MINUTE($Whenـyouـwantـitـtoـstart),5) = 0  AND `time` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%H:%i'),`value` FROM users WHERE  MOD(MINUTE((NOW()),5) = 0 
AND `time` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

If you want to have time without seconds you should use:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%H:%i')
```

query below select rows in last 7 days

```
WHERE `time` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

and MOD(N,M) function returns the remainder of a number divided by another number. you can use it like this:

```
WHERE MOD(MINUTE("2020-02-28 08:45:00"),5)=0
```